# "The following branches form a loop of rigid branches (shorts) when added to the circuit" error in Hspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, spice, circuit-protection, hspice

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsANN9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to do the transient analysis of this circuit.

Given, Initial Conditions I(L0.1-)=10A, I(L0.4-)=20A

```
simulator lang=spice
R200 1 0 200
R40 1 2 40
R60 2 0 60
L0.1 2 0 0.1 IC=10
L0.4 2 0 0.4 IC=20
.OP
.TRAN 1m 50m
.END
```

I am getting this error

```
Fatal error found by spectre during topology check.
        FATAL: The following branches form a loop of rigid branches (shorts) when added to the circuit:
            L0.1:1 (from 2 to 0)
```

Can anyone help me what is the reason?

Comment: Where is your voltage source?

Comment: I just wondering if the transient analysis is having trouble because with no voltage applied what can it calculate?  You're node connections are listed "from 2 to 0" are you certain the compiler doesn't require the lower number node be named first?

Comment: @KH if you check my code I had written initial conditions of the inductor.it is a source less circuit. check it now I have edited it.

Comment: Oh interesting.  I did not know that was allowed.  I would note those two inductors are directly in parallel, so if you've pulled 10A and 20A out of the air those values may lead to conflicting assertions, assuming the solver is meant to solve that way in the first place.

Comment: What sort of value is `0.4H H`?

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry Its a typo. First time I am drawing this circuit in circuitLAB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inductors are internally represented as voltage sources, so unless you have some series resistance in there, somewhere, the circuit sees two voltage sources in parallel, which is not possible. The same for two current sources in series.

You can either add some minor resistance (something like 1 mΩ, or so) in series with any of the two, so that the local loop includes that resistance, or combine the two inductors into an equivalent one, `L1 || L2`.

Comment: "Inductors are internally represented as voltage sources"  can you explain this point I thought it is a current source and in this case also it showing as a current source which was initially, let say 10A and with time it is decreasing.

Comment: Inductors induce a voltage that opposes the change of current,  so thinking of them as a voltage source can make sense.  The problem probably occurs any time it asserts a voltage drop over 0 resistance, regardless of source as It's a mathematical impossibility.